# Why Flutter Floor DAO findAll returns entity set with null ids?

Tags: flutter, auto-increment, dao, sqflite

This is a Flutter project using Floor (package equivalent of Jetpack's Room).
I have an entity with an auto increment id *(note that this is pre null-safety code, in the answer I start now with post null safety snippet)*:

```
const String ACTIVITIES_TABLE_NAME = 'activities';

@Entity(
  tableName: ACTIVITIES_TABLE_NAME,
  indices: [
    Index(value: ['start'])
  ],
)
class Activity {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int id;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_name')
  final String deviceName;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_id')
  final String deviceId;
  final int start;

  Activity({
    this.deviceName,
    this.deviceId,
    this.start,
  });
}
```

I have this DAO:

```
@dao
abstract class ActivityDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM $ACTIVITIES_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY start DESC')
  Future<List<Activity>> findAllActivities();

  @insert
  Future<int> insertActivity(Activity activity);
}
```

In my app I recorded five activities so far, hunky-dory.

```
_database =
    await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('app_database.db').build();
...
    _activity =
       Activity(deviceName: device.name, deviceId: device.id.id, start: _lastRecord.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    final id = await _database.activityDao.insertActivity(_activity);
    _activity.id = id;
```

Then in another view I list them, but there is a lurking problem.

```
final data = await _database.activityDao.findAllActivities();
```

When I query the entities with this dead simple method, all the five or so activities in my DB are returned with an `id` field filled with `null`. That makes the entity completely useless because any other operation I would like to perform on it fails due to lack of actual id. Am I doing something wrong?

I mostly have experience with MySQL, Postgres and non SQLite RDBMS. As I understand in SQLite every row has a unique `rowid`, and by declaring my auto increment `id` primary key field basically I alias that rowid? Whatever it is, I need the id. It cannot be null.

---

I'm debugging the guts of Floor.

```
  Future<List<T>> queryList<T>(
    final String sql, {
    final List<dynamic> arguments,
    @required final T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) mapper,
  }) async {
    final rows = await _database.rawQuery(sql, arguments);
    return rows.map((row) => mapper(row)).toList();
  }
```

At this point the `rows` still have the ids filled in properly, although the entities in the rows are just a list of dynamic values. The `rows.map` supposed to map them to the entity objects, and that cannot carry the id over for some reason? Can this be a Floor bug?

---

Ok, now I see that in the generated `database.g.dart` the mapper does not have the id:

```
  static final _activitiesMapper = (Map<String, dynamic> row) => Activity(
      deviceName: row['device_name'] as String,
      deviceId: row['device_id'] as String,
      start: row['start'] as int);
```

That explains it why id is `null` then. But this is generated code, how can I tell Floor I need the id? Or why should I tell it, it has to be there by default, who wouldn't want to know the primary key of an object?

Comment: Filed a ticket https://github.com/vitusortner/floor/issues/401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this is because I didn't have the the `id` as a constructor parameter. I didn't have that because it's an auto increment field and I'm not the one who determines it. However without having it as a constructor argument, the generated code cannot pass it along with the mapper as a parameter, so it leaves it out from the mapper. So I added the id as a constructor argument.

Post null-safety version:

```
class Activity {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int? id;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_name')
  final String deviceName;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_id')
  final String deviceId;
  final int start;
  final int end;

  Activity({
    this.id,
    required this.deviceName,
    required this.deviceId,
    required this.start,
    this.end: 0,
  });
}
```

I also add this Floor GitHub issue here, it looks like in the future there might be an annotation: https://github.com/vitusortner/floor/issues/527

---

Pre null-safety version:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Activity {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int id;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_name')
  @required
  final String deviceName;
  @ColumnInfo(name: 'device_id')
  @required
  final String deviceId;
  final int start;

  Activity({
    this.id: null,
    this.deviceName,
    this.deviceId,
    this.start,
  });
}
```

The compiler is a little iffy about the null, but after the `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` the `database.g.dart`'s mappers have the `id` as well.